# Albania to Italy with interrail pass

Tags: international-travel, italy, ferries, interrail, albania

I'm currently in Sarande, Albania and I want to travel to Italy with Ferry.

I have an Interrail pass and I can't figure out what the most economical way will be for me to get to Italy.

Does anyone know whether the ferries going from Corfu to Italy are included in the interrail pass? Info online is conflicting and confusing.

Is there any way I can get to Italy without paying using my interrail pass?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Corfu is in Greece, so this question using Albania is misleading. See: [Superfast Ferries from Greece to Italy | Interrail.eu](https://www.interrail.eu/en/plan-your-trip/trains-europe/ferries/superfast-ferries), where conditions for Interail from Corfu are listed depending on which type of pass you have.